# Audio not updating correctly after setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, state

I have a website that plays podcasts of the user's choice. However, I am finding that the first podcast that is selected is the only one that is played by the audio player. The state is updated correctly for everything else other than the audio.

Here is my code for when the selected podcast changes. Here, the array of episodes is updated to the tracks of the newly selected podcast.

```
useEffect(() =>{
        
        if (!selectedPodcast){
            // Landing page
            return
        }
        else {
            var url = `/feed?url=${selectedPodcast.feed}`
            axios({
                url,
                method: 'get'
            })
            .then(({data}) => {
                var {item} = data
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(item))
                var tracks = item.map((t, index) =>{
                    return {
                        id: index,
                        title: t.title[0],
                        image: selectedPodcast.image,
                        trackUrl: t.enclosure[0]['$'].url,
                        author: data.title

                    }
                    
                })

                setEpisodes(tracks)

            })
            .catch(err => {
            })
        }
    }, [selectedPodcast])
```

And here is the episode component

```
const Episode = ({title, image, trackUrl, author}) => {
    const loadAudio = () => {
        console.log('audio should be reloaded')
    }

    return (
        <div className="d-block d-md-flex podcast-entry bg-white mb-5">
            <div className="image" style={{backgroundImage : `url('${image}')`}}></div>
            <div className="text">
                <h3 className="font-weight-light"><a>{title}</a></h3>
                <div className="text-white mb-3"><span className="text-black-opacity-05"><small>{author} </small></span></div>

                <div className="player">
                        <audio id="player2" preload="auto" controls controlsList="nodownload" style={{width: '100%'}}>
                            <source src={trackUrl} type="audio/mp3"/>
                        </audio>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The trackUrl is what is giving me trouble. If I console log the current list of episodes, I will get the correct result. But when I go to play the audio, it is the same audio as the first podcast to be selected.